# How can I remove the Suspend and Hibernate options from the power menu?

Tags: indicator

I want to get rid of the Hibernate and Suspend options on the top-right menu in Unity. These do not work on my netbook and having them close to "logout" is not useful.

Comment: As this is the first answer from the Google.
If your using a later version of Ubuntu (> 13.XX, it seems) try this answer instead https://askubuntu.com/questions/452908/how-to-disable-suspend-in-14-04

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using a much earlier distro since this post is apparently from 5 months ago. Anyway, I just did the opposite of what you're doing yesterday on Precise. Run the following command to open the file to edit:

`sudo gedit /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla`

Scroll to the bottom. Check to see if the following information exists, and if not add them:

```
[Disable hibernate]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=no

[Disable suspend]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.suspend
ResultActive=no
```

Doing this makes those options do nothing when you click them; they will disappear from the menu after you restart your computer.

Comment: Does not work in 13.10

Comment: Nor in 14.04...

Comment: Didn't work on Ubuntu 16.04:(