# How to disable suspend in 14.04?

Tags: suspend, 14.04

For some reason Ubuntu had not been having good support for suspend. Creating the `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.disable-suspend.pkla` file with the below disabled suspend option in the main menu in 12.04. But, the same doesn't work after moving from 12.04 to 14.04.

```
[Disable suspend by default]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.suspend
ResultActive=no
```

How to disable suspend in 14.04?

Comment: bug report about this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit/+bug/1300460

Comment: @Rinzwind: The OP has not tried in the file mentioned in the bug report, the OP has mentioned a different file.

Comment: If only we were able to suppress the menu entry: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-session/+bug/1299753

Comment: Unfortunately the workaround does not help. I found that hint here too: https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/bugs#TOC-Hibernate-and-suspend-don-t-always-work-well:-they-make-some-computers-malfunction-or-even-enter-a-coma But did not help neither...

Answer (score 30):

Create a new file called `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.disable-suspend.pkla` with the following contents:

```
[Disable suspend (upower)]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.suspend
ResultActive=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultAny=no

[Disable suspend (logind)]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.suspend
ResultActive=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultAny=no

[Disable suspend when others are logged in (logind)]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.suspend-multiple-sessions
ResultActive=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultAny=no
```

and then reboot.

This tells PolicyKit to automatically say "no" whenever anything asks if it's OK/possible to suspend.  Logout menus will react to this by automatically removing the 'Suspend' menu choice.

I don't quite understand why, but the `upower` setting is needed for KDE but does not affect Unity.  The `login1` settings are needed for Unity but do not affect KDE.

Comment: Awesome :) Still works for 18.04, Bionic Beaver!

Comment: This also seems to work in 21.10. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

For me it is important to *just* disable the **"automatic Suspend"**
Because I still want to be able to do the **"manual Suspend"**
in `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.disable-suspend.pkla`

So, I used:

```
[Disable suspend (upower)]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.suspend
ResultActive=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultAny=no

[Disable suspend (logind)]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.suspend
ResultActive=yes
ResultInactive=no
ResultAny=yes

[Disable suspend when others are logged in (logind)]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.suspend-multiple-sessions
ResultActive=yes
ResultInactive=no
ResultAny=yes
```

Now I can click "Suspend" in the logoff menu. But the PC keeps running unless I send it to "Suspend".

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work anymore in 16.04: My laptop still goes to sleep after about 5 idle minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. This is a bug in polkit in 14.04. As a workaround, you can

```
chmod 000 /usr/lib/pm-utils/bin/pm-action
```

It would help if you vote up the above-mentioned launchpad bug.

Comment: Changed the permissions as mentioned and Suspend was still enabled. ---------- 1 root root 2903 Nov  6 16:26 pm-action

Comment: It's still in the menu - only polkit can change that - but choosing it should have no effect now, because pm-action will fail to run.