# How to prevent automatic suspend/sleep after long period of inactivity?

Tags: 14.04, suspend, power-management

I have a Dell Precision workstation T7400 with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed with Gnome Classic Desktop. I usually lock the workstation which can be unlocked if it is locked for a few hours. But if I leave it overnight, the next day the workstation seems to be in possibly a suspended state. The keyboard lights are on, but the mouse or keyboard remains inactive. Powering on the machine also does not respond, the whole workstation is in a frozen state. I have a couple of questions regarding this issue. In the power settings tab, "Don't suspend" is already checked.

1. Does Ubuntu 14.04 have automatic suspend option and what is the time required for automatic suspending?
2. How to prevent this from happening? I don't want the workstation to sleep at all.

Comment: Is there anything of interest in the system log?

Comment: This might help. Please take a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/473037/how-to-permanently-disable-sleep-suspend) and [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25133/ubuntu-server-continuously-goes-to-sleep/25151#25151).

Comment: @rabra Even after trying those it does not work. I can't access the terminal also with ctrl+alt+f1.