# Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS won't wake up after extended AFK periods

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, suspend

For the past few days, every morning I come in I have to reboot my workstation. Previously, I had disabled suspend on it (I don't recall how) and the issue went away, but a few days ago I installed some updates and it started this behavior again.

Symptoms:

- Workstation is on
- Screen is off
- I can ssh into it
- I can't turn the screen on
- I can cycle between `systemctl isolate multi-user.target` and `systemctl isolate graphical.target` to get the screen to turn on, but mouse and keyboard still don't respond.
- I can only reboot to be able to use it and it takes a long time to reboot

HW Info:

- Dell Precision 5820
- Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2295 CPU @ 3.00GHz
- nVidia Quadro P2200 (Driver: `nvidia-driver-460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1`)

OS Release:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Kernel (`uname -a`):

```
Linux XXXXXX 5.8.0-44-generic #50~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 10 21:07:30 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I've tried [This solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473037/how-to-permanently-disable-sleep-suspend) to no avail.