# Ubuntu 20.04.02 LTS all USB ports stop working

Tags: 20.04, usb

My workstation (Dell Precision 5820) works fine for the most part until all the USB ports suddenly stop working. `lsusb` takes a while to show the connected devices, but adding new devices or removing old ones doesn't update the list. Also none of the connected devices actually work:

- Moving the mouse doesn't move the cursor
- None of the keyboard keys do anything
- My Android Tablet shows as 'offline'

This is the output from `dmesg` when this happens:

```
[203609.113150] usb 2-5: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[203609.219797] usb 2-5: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 92 using xhci_hcd
[203609.543980] usb 2-5: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 93 using xhci_hcd
[203614.745151] usb 2-5: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[203614.851794] usb 2-5: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 93 using xhci_hcd
[203615.431901] usb 2-5: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 94 using xhci_hcd
[203620.633142] usb 2-5: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[203620.739796] usb 2-5: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 94 using xhci_hcd
[203621.067254] usb 2-5: Device not responding to setup address.
[203621.275248] usb 2-5: Device not responding to setup address.
[203621.479788] usb 2-5: device not accepting address 95, error -71
[203621.479864] usb usb2-port5: attempt power cycle
[203621.927254] usb 2-5: Device not responding to setup address.
[203622.135258] usb 2-5: Device not responding to setup address.
[203622.339787] usb 2-5: device not accepting address 96, error -71
[203622.535842] usb 2-5: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 97 using xhci_hcd
[203627.801096] usb 2-5: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[203627.907782] usb 2-5: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 97 using xhci_hcd
[203628.811879] usb 2-5: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 98 using xhci_hcd
[203633.945147] usb 2-5: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[203634.051781] usb 2-5: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 98 using xhci_hcd
[203634.375873] usb 2-5: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 99 using xhci_hcd
[203639.577149] usb 2-5: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[203639.683769] usb 2-5: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 99 using xhci_hcd
[203639.819980] usb usb2-port5: attempt power cycle
[203640.539942] usb 2-5: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 100 using xhci_hcd
[203645.721160] usb 2-5: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[203645.827756] usb 2-5: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 100 using xhci_hcd
[203646.151859] usb 2-5: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 101 using xhci_hcd
[203651.353160] usb 2-5: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[203651.459766] usb 2-5: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 101 using xhci_hcd
[203652.039837] usb 2-5: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 102 using xhci_hcd
[203657.241158] usb 2-5: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[203657.347767] usb 2-5: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 102 using xhci_hcd
[203657.671845] usb 2-5: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 103 using xhci_hcd
[203662.873165] usb 2-5: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[203662.979758] usb 2-5: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 103 using xhci_hcd
[203663.107825] usb usb2-port5: attempt power cycle
[203663.551885] usb 2-5: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 104 using xhci_hcd
[203668.761166] usb 2-5: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[203668.867750] usb 2-5: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 104 using xhci_hcd
[203669.191947] usb 2-5: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 105 using xhci_hcd
```

The only thing that brings it back is a reboot.

I suspect this is really the cause of [my other issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1319626/ubuntu-20-04-2-lts-wont-wake-up-after-extended-afk-periods) ... I think the issue isn't that it won't wake up, but that it isn't receiving the events.

HW Info:

- Dell Precision 5820
- Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2295 CPU @ 3.00GHz
- nVidia Quadro P2200 (Driver: `nvidia-driver-460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1`)

OS Release:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Kernel (`uname -a`):

```
Linux XXXXXX 5.8.0-44-generic #50~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 10 21:07:30 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```