# How to keep my computer "not idle"?

Tags: idle

I have Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.
Now, it gets “suspended” or “sleep” when left alone (watching a movie inclusive) for more than 10-15 minutes.
I tried to follow what https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/07/caffeine-indicator-applet-ubuntu-lock-screen, [How do I disable my system from going to sleep?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47311/how-do-i-disable-my-system-from-going-to-sleep), and [How to permanently disable sleep/suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473037/how-to-permanently-disable-sleep-suspend) advised, but to no avail.
Whether from the same source or not, the Internet connection breaks more than once a day, so I have to restart the PC to get it back.
Please, help.

Comment: "so I have to restart the PC to get it back" No and absolutely not how Linux works.  There is always a method to reset your network without a reboot. "How to keep my computer "not idle"?" is that not the wrong question(??)  "it gets “suspended” or “sleep” when left alone " that is the default. Switch to "do nothing" to disable suspend/hibernate. That will also keep wireless active during lid close.

Comment: There are several answers in those links so which ones did you follow?  Also, please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1458241/edit) your question and add more details about your system like the output of `sudo lshw -C network` as the network going down I have seen where the system has a RTL8111/8168 chipset but yet the `r8169` driver is loaded and that can fail on the 8168 chipset and be very unpredictable.

Comment: Rinzwind, what you recommended I did. And got zero result. That's why "the wrong question" got here.

Comment: Terrance, that's what I got:                                                               *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 09
       serial: 60:a4:4c:3b:ee:12
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz

Comment: Best to install the `r8168` driver.  `sudo apt install r8168-dkms`

Comment: Have you tried Power Settings - R. click desktop->Display->Power? Under Power Saving Options, set Screen Blank to 'Never' and disable Automatic Suspend.

Comment: E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ jammy: /etc/apt/keyrings/winehq-archive.key != /usr/share/keyrings/winehq.gpg
E: The list of sources could not be read.