# Laptop sleeps even though sleep is disabled despite power and screen settings

Tags: 22.04, suspend, power-management, laptop, hibernate

relatively new to Ubuntu, using 22.04 LTS.

Using it on my laptop and every time I lock my computer screen, the computer goes to sleep. I don't want this. I want it to stay on the lock screen, at least while plugged in I do not want to computer going to sleep whatsoever.

I configured this in the power and sleep settings and it doesn't seem to be listening, I do not know why.

Here are the screenshots of the settings.

[image: Sleep Settings]

[image: Power Settings]

I've even tried a few terminal commands I got from google setting a state to 0 and even tried and app called Caffeine.

Any help? At a loss here, it's really annoying me more than it probablu should.

Comment: Related: [How to permanently disable sleep/suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/q/473037)

Comment: [How to permanently disable sleep/suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/q/473037) none of the suggestions here worked.