# How do I disable the automatic fade to black on lock? (15.04)

Tags: unity, suspend, 15.04, lock-screen, debug

I have an issue where I lock my desktop, and it will fade to black almost immediately. It does not always resume correctly when "waking up", so I'd like to disable the fading entirely.

I have tried these things found in other threads:

- Brightness & Lock - Lock is set to "Off"
- Brightness & Lock -  "Turn screen off when inactive" is set to "Never"
- I have uninstalled gnome-screensaver
- I have also tried creating a disable suspend config as described
  here:
  [How to disable suspend in 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452908/how-to-disable-suspend-in-14-04)
- My power settings are: Don't suspend when inactive.

Running Ubuntu 15.04, Unity