# How can I force my computer to sleep?

Tags: suspend

On another forum, I looked up a way to warn me when my computer would go to sleep. Unfortunately, instead of a warning, my computer doesn't sleep at all. The main problem is, I don't remember the code I put in. I'm a new Linux user (obviously) and now realize that I should be a bit more careful. Any advice? Thank you. Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for command, it is this:

```
sudo pm-suspend
```

Comment: You might need to `apt install pm-utils`

Answer (score 0):

I am a noob so I hope this is what you want...

(all clicks are left clicks)

1) Go to the **little cog** in top right hand corner of the screen, click on it.

2) Click on first item **System settings**

3) Click on **power** (battery icon)

You have two drop down menus that should help you to do what you want.

You can tweak brightness there too...

If you are looking for the terminal solution take a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452908/how-to-disable-suspend-in-14-04)

There is an option for manual override.

Good luck.