# How can I get a warning prompt for "Suspend"

Tags: 16.04, suspend, notification

I have some problem with my Nvidia Graphics and suspending (I can't resume from suspend). So I usually avoid suspending my computer.

But sometimes I *accidentally* click on **`Suspend`** when trying to Shutdown. Which suddenly suspends my computer **without giving any warning!**.  I will have to boot it again (*where I get stuck on a blank screen*) and long press my <kbd>power-button</kbd> and restart my computer.

[image]

I get a warning like this  before shutting down.

[image]

I would like to get a similar warning when I accidentally click on **`Suspend`**  too.

Comment: There may be other methods to solve your original problem. For example: fixing suspend, making the suspend option to shutdown instead, removing the option from the menu. Are you interested in them too? In particular, I suspect that removing the Suspend entry from the menu is a matter of a couple shell commands.

Comment: @Sergey I have tried a _lot_ to fix the suspend problem, but I could not get it working. 
Suspend works fine when I switch to Intel graphics using Nvidia-prime. I use suspend when Intel graphics is being used.
So , I am searching for a script/any other method to get a warning (simple one, zenity would do) before it suspends.

Comment: @Sergey But Yes, I am interested in "making the suspend option to shutdown instead". do you know how to do that ?

Comment: See this question for suggestions how to remove the Suspend option from the menu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/452908/how-to-disable-suspend-in-14-04

Comment: As suggested, I have raised a **feature request** on launchpad for getting this feature .

Link : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1593912

If you support this feature, please mark as "Yes, it affects me"

Answer (score 5):

While modifying the source  of the indicator itself ( in my humble opinion ) is the best approach ( and probably the feature request for that is even better approach ) ，one can create custom session control to be placed onto the launcher , which is fairly easy to achieve. That way, we can have `suspend` options which does ask for user confirmation.

The `.desktop` file bellow allows mimicking the 3 options from the session indicator in the top panel: Shutdown , Suspend , and Logout. Double clicking on the icon by default will bring up confirmation for shutdown. Right clicking on the entry will bring up the list of other options.

Preferably , you'd want it to be stored in `~/local/share/applications` folder and have executable permissions. Naming doesn't matter, personally I named it `session-control.desktop`

**File contents**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Shutdown the System
Comment=Alternative session control , main entry will bring up shutdown or reboot dialog but Suspend and Logout will bring up confirmation dialog.
Terminal=false
Actions=Suspend;Logout
Type=Application
Exec=qdbus com.canonical.Unity /com/canonical/Unity/Session com.canonical.Unity.Session.RequestReboot
Icon=/usr/share/unity-greeter/cof.png

[Desktop Action Suspend]
Name=Suspend the System
Exec=qdbus com.canonical.Unity /com/canonical/Unity/Session com.canonical.Unity.Session.RequestShutdown
Terminal=false

[Desktop Action Logout]
Name=Logout the User
Exec=qdbus com.canonical.Unity /com/canonical/Unity/Session com.canonical.Unity.Session.RequestLogout
Terminal=false
```

**How it looks**

Launcher entry

[image: Launcher entry with all options visible]

The dialog that comes up if you click on Suspend

[image: Unity's shutdown dialog that comes up when you click on Suspend option, among others Suspend is there on the dialog as well]

Comment: when used your method, not able to apply with confirmation box, did i need to d0 anything else?

Comment: @solfish  Are you using a desktop environment that is not Unity ?