# How to disable sleep and keep lock screen in xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, suspend, power-management

I know this sleep-issues seem like an ever-again-question, but I have not found a proper answer yet.

My problem is as follows:

- I disabled sleep on xfce power manager (and light locker settings) and set `when laptop lid is closed` to `switch off display`. Then I go for lock screen on the whisker menu, close the laptop lid and get a cup of coffee. Open the lid, type my password in, see my windows and work for a second before the laptop goes to sleep. I then have to *hard* power off and start over again.
- I then researched and read and tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452908/how-to-disable-suspend-in-14-04#488300). It works, apparently I cannot click on sleep nowhere now. But I cannot click on lock screen. I mean, I *can* click on the button, but it does nothing.

**Is it possible to keep [at least] the manual lock screen and prevent xubuntu from going to sleep (ever)?**