# Machine won't wake from hibernate, pixelated screen and I can't log in

Tags: 16.04, unity, hibernate

Exactly as the title says: when my machine goes into hibernation I can't wake it back up without getting a pixelated screen, as below:

[image]

[image]

I can't see the mouse moving, can't log in and I have to perform a hard restart. I can reproduce this behavior by locking my machine and waiting for it to go into hibernate on its own (~30 seconds). I tried to disable hibernate by following the instructions in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452908/how-to-disable-suspend-in-14-04), to no avail.

The following is my video card output, for which the driver is the latest:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 67ef (rev cf) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 22de
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=2M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Memory at fea00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Expansion ROM at fea40000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [200] #15
    Capabilities: [270] #19
    Capabilities: [2b0] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [2c0] #13
    Capabilities: [2d0] #1b
    Capabilities: [320] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [328] Alternative Routing-ID Interpretation (ARI)
    Capabilities: [370] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
```